# In Node.js using Express, restrict access to a route based on user credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

In express app where users login using their web identities (google, facebook, amazon, etc) using passport.js for this. I have created a route. but only want that a single user should have access to it. 
I have it working with extensive testing, but not entirely sure if its in fact secure enough?
Here is my code for the route:

```
app.get("/superSecretPage", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.user);
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    if (req.user.userId === "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") {
      User.find({}, function(err, users){
        res.render("userlist", {
          users: users,
          });
      });
    } else {
    res.render("invalid")
    }

  } else {
    res.redirect("login")
  }
});
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX = being the users uniqueID from Google/Amazon/Facebook or another ID provider

Like i said this work, and only allows the user that equals req.user.userId, but is this secure enough?

Comment: Are you using passportjs?

Comment: HI, Yes I'm using passport.js.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not a** proper way to do that. What will you do If you want to allow another user later? Will you open code and edit the `user Id`?

**Do not** hard code the `user ID`.

You need to implement [Role Base Access Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control). You need to create a **super power user role** and assign it to the users, Who you want to allow to access your **super secret page**. And use **middlewares** to check the role permissions.

> **This will help you :** [Role based auth | NodeJS](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/11/28/nodejs-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example-api)

Comment: Thanks! But in this case i will only ever want this one user (me) to have the access. If this being the case, is it still not a good implementation for access?

Comment: Of-course No. However do not hard code such values.

Comment: As Im still learning all this, I have another question for you. If I put the userID in a .env file would that be better? and also security wise, is it possible for another to spoof that same userID to get access to the "secret page"

Answer (score 0):

> Like i said this work, and only allows the user that equals req.user.userId, but is this secure enough?

You haven't really shown enough to know about the overall security of this.  The security depends upon at least the following:

1. Implementation of `req.isAuthenticated()`
2. How the user session was established and protected.  Most sessions use a browser cookie to identify the session and it must be run over https to offer any protection.  Then, you must also have proper auto-logout to make it less likely the session is just left active where someone else can use it on that computer.
3. How the `req.user.userId` got set in the first place.  You don't show this so we really have no idea what is behind that and whether it's following good security practices or not.
4. If there is any persistent storage of the user session, then the security of that storage mechanism is relevant.
5. Presuming there's a login mechanism, are secure (hard to guess) credentials required?  Are there anti-hacking protections in place to attempt to thwart credential guessing.

If you are 100% sure that `req.user.userId` is valid and that this connection belongs to the appropriate user for the userId, then this bit of code works fine.  But, the devil is in the details of making sure that `req.user.userId` is appropriately connected to an authorized user and that's where the hard work is of making security work.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field in the db schema and set it to an array which contains all the route that the user has access to. When authenticating loop through the array to see if he/she can access the route he/she is trying to.